# Bootstrap - divide container

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

What is the best approch to divide a container and make sure it expands?

I have the following code

```
                        <div class="input-group">

                        <label for="passwordInput">Password</label>

                        <div class="input-group">

                            <div class="col-xs-6">

                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="passwordInput"> 

                            </div>

                            <div class="col-xs-6">

                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="passwordReTypeInput">

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
```

but the end result is not what I'm after.[image]

**UPDATE**

I changed the class to"container-fluid" and it now expands, I just need to remove the edges I think.

Comment: The col-xs-* contains padding/margin from about lets say `15px`, if you put it in a row class, so: `<div class="row"><div class="col-xs-6">` it will change the padding back and align the elements. See more about grids: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

Comment: @C0dekid.php thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome @marco :)